# Dictionary with generics

Tags: c#, covariance

I've got the following interfaces:

```
public interface IObjectFinder<T> where T : IObject
{
    Task<IObjectResults<T>> FindAsync(string name);
}

public interface IObject
{
    string Id { get; }
}
```

I'd like to initialize a dictionary with the following:

```
this.finders = new Dictionary<string, IObjectFinder<IObject>>();
finders.Add("Car", new CarFinder<Car>());
finders.Add("Truck", new TruckFinder<Truck>());
```

Then create a simple controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult>(string objectType, string searchTerm)
{
    if (!finders.TryGetValue(objectType, out var finder))
        return NotFound();

    var result = await finder.FindAsync(searchTerm);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The problem is the `IObjectFinder<IObject>` type of dictionary. A `CarFinder<Car>` isn't an `IObjectFinder<IObject>`. Is there an objectively better way to handle this? I'd like to avoid using `MorseCode.ITask` and dynamic's to avoid muddying up the code even more. How would you handle something like this?

Comment: Are you saying that `CarFinder<T>` does not implement `IObjectFinder<T>`? Why not?

Comment: @PMF I can't cast `CarFinder<Car>` to `IObjectFinder<IObject>` for the dictionary. The dictionary needs to be able to return different types of `IObject`. The Dictionary can't be `IObjectFinder<T>` because then it would be restricted to one specific type.

Comment: I see the problem. You probably need a non-generic `IObjectFinder` type. I think there's no way around a cast at some place, since objectType is a string. And you will need to tell the compiler that the string "Car" relates to the type "CarFinder" at some place.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can accomplish that @PMF?

Comment: @shingo because of missing covariance. you cannot assign an `IObjectFinder<Car>` to  an `IObjectFinder<IObject>` variable. It should be declared as `IObjectFinder<out IObject>`

Comment: You could certainly make the interfaces covariant (using the out keyword) and use something like MorseCode.ITask for a covariant Task implementation.

Comment: @shingo There'd only be one implementation of finder to an object. CarFinder is currently defined as `CarFinder : IObjectFinder<Car>` in my code. `IObjectFinder` cannot be covariant, because it uses Task which unfortunately is not covariant. (I'd need to use `MorseCode.ITask` which IMO muddies up the code a bit.) I'm curious if there is a better way to go about doing this.

Comment: @SirRufo no, I just realized that `Task<T>` is invariant, so `IObjectFinder` cannot be covariant.

Comment: Like I said, I feel like having to use `ITask` here from a separate library complicates things, and screams to me what I'm doing isn't the best way. That's why I'm hoping to have a better take from the community about how to go about doing this.

Comment: My goal was to use a constructor with `IEnumerable<IObjectFinder>`  and use scrutor to scan the assembly to add them to DI. That way adding a new engine would be simply implementing another `IObjectFinder`. (`IObjectFinder` is another interface with a "Name" property) that `IObjectFinder<T>` extends, and I use for the dictionary.

Comment: @Blue, I have a question, since the value type is `IObjectFinder<IObject>`, whichever finder is added to the dictionary, you can only get an `IObject` object with `FindAsync` in the end. So If you just need an `IObject` object, why not define `CarFinder : IObjectFinder<IObject>`?

Comment: @shingo Is it not prudent to define the actual type of the object when initializing the class? I know in the search controller I could be fetching anything, but in other cases, I may actually want the `Car` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I thought some more, I think it's similar to how some generic interfaces (e.g. `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator`) are defined. We need to define some non-generic interfaces first:

```
public interface IObjectResults
{
}

public interface IObjectFinder
{
    Task<IObjectResults> FindAsync(string name);
}
```

The generic interfaces need inherit them, and benefit from the default interface methods feature, we can implement them in this place.

```
public interface IObjectResults<T> : IObjectResults where T : IObject
{
}

public interface IObjectFinder<T> : IObjectFinder where T : IObject
{
    new Task<IObjectResults<T>> FindAsync(string name);

    async Task<IObjectResults> IObjectFinder.FindAsync(string name)
        => await FindAsync(name);
}
```

Now it's able to replace `IObjectFinder<IObject>` with `IObjectFinder` in the dictionary.

```
this.finders = new Dictionary<string, IObjectFinder>();
finders.Add("Car", new CarFinder());

var result = await finder.FindAsync(searchTerm);
```